# Joomla search in specific category

Tags: search, joomla, categories

For my website I have a category which contains articles related to FAQ items. The standard search function searches the whole site and offers no personalization.

**I need to search only in one specific category with a search module in Joomla , what would the easiest way to do that?**

I have tried Smart Search, unchecking all other categories and indexing again. Still, results from other categories show up in the Smart Search module. Also I have seen the Filter option in the Smart Search module, but I haven't found out how that should work.

I am using Joomla 3. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems I have solved my question myself.

My solution was to add a filter at the Manage Smart Search page on the Search Filters tab, then choosing the category I wanted to search in.

Then, in the smart search module you choose that particular filter and you will only search in that particular category!

Comment: @Elin I cannot accept my own answer yet, that is possible tomorrow and I will do it then.